# How are the votes on curling shots determined?

Tags: ranking, curling

During curling matches it is easy to check the percentage for each shot of for each player, but how are those values determined?

Each shots can be classified with the following values: 0% - 25% - 50% - 75% - 100%

Sometimes it is easy to determine the real value, but how in this case (see the picture):

- stone #15 the tem green would like to draw a point (closer than the yellow one). If the green stone is closer to the yellow it takes 100%, if it was farther it takes 0% (I believe so).

How is it possible to classificate this shot considering that is not possible to take a measure before the shot of #16?

[image: curling_point]

Comment: If something it is not clear you can write what part is not clear to edit the question. In my mind is so clear

Comment: It appears you have given a rule (100% for shot rock, 0% for not shot rock).  Are you asking if the rule is correct?

Comment: If you can't tell between 0 and 100, and there's no difference otherwise, you'd go with 50, surely.

Comment: After the shot #16 you can ask for the measurment to check what stones is the closest to the center

Comment: I didn't ask this question, but I'm very confused about what is being asked, and the answer. How do 3 or 4 points relate to 0%, 100% etc? Is the question about which stone is closer to the center? It says "closer to the yellow", but I think the stones are supposed to be close to the center, not each other?

Answer (score 2):

Statistics is a very demanding job. Not only do you have to give points for every stone, you also register the type of stone (draw, take out …), the curl (in or out-turn) and place the stone in the house for the shot-by-shot coverage you will find for many of the major competitions.

There are guidelines (mostly by the providers of the statistics software) how to give the points for each stone. Most important is what was intended, how (well) was this achieved and could the player have done better. You also need to consider the other stone in play. Is there a guard you could hide behind, should this have been a freeze, etc.?

In your specific example you would probably give 3 or 4 points. As a rough guideline you can say, ‘be in favour of the player’. You are right, you do not know which is closer, but you also do not know what will happen with the next stones. The question ‘will this stone give a point at the end’ is only relevant for the last stone of the end, for the others it is ‘was the stone played as intended’. So in your case the objective being a draw into the house (achieved) and laying shot (not clear), you will never get 0 points, most likely, as I said, 3 or 4 points.

You also have viewing limitations, when doing the stats you will almost never be able to see the house from the top like this, you always have a slant view. You are seated behind the coaches, media and timers, as high up as possible, you do have the best view in the arena but you also have to work hard for it ;).

No statistic is completely neutral and objective, you will find many occasions where players would get different points from different people doing the stats. However in general you would expect these differences to average out over a game.